# memory allocation issue of char* in windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, windows-10

I have created a c++ dll in visual studio 2010 in which there are two variables of type char*(both not initialized).I have assigned values to these by using different methods.Please see the snippet

```
char* a;
char* b;
a = strtok(input,"^");
GetClassName(handle,b,255);
...
//definition of GetClassName
WINUSERAPI
int
WINAPI
GetClassName(
__in HWND hWnd,
__out_ecount_part(nMaxCount, return) LPSTR lpClassName,
__in int nMaxCount
);
```

The above code fails in **WINDOWS 10**. It works on windows 7,8.

When I initialized char* b like `char* b =new char;`, It started working on windows 10,although I initialized only b and char* a is still uninitialized.
When I initialized char* b to NULL, it didn't work.

Is there any memory allocation issue in windows 10? Also I want to know is there any downside in initializing char* like that.

Comment: _"The above code fails"_ _"it didn't work"_ What **exactly** did you see? Where is your [MCVE]? Provide a rigourous and scientific description of your problem; if you do not have one, then you have not yet concluded your own phase of debugging. Also, what prevented you from simply reading [the documentation for the functions you used](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry I'm new here. From now on I'll follow  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example when asking question. I have gone through the documentation, but I'm wondering how it is working on windows7,8 but not on windows 10

Comment: It's not; it only appears to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`GetClassName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx) expects an "array" of character to write to as the second argument. The length of the array is passed as the third argument.

If you pass an uninitialized pointer as the second argument, then you will have *undefined behavior* as the pointer will point to an indeterminate location. I.e. the `GetClassName` function will write to some seemingly random location in memory.

The easiest way to call it is by declaring an array and passing it and its size as arguments:

```
char b[256];
GetClassName(handle, b, sizeof b);
```

As for why it seems to work sometimes and not other times, it's just because of the *undefined behavior*. One of the possibilities is *seemingly* working.

And when you do `b = new char` you only allocate a *single character*. It will only be able to hold a null-terminated byte string of size zero, since all it can contain is the terminator. Passing anything than `1` as the size to `GetClassName` will lead to the function writing out of bounds of your allocated memory, and you will again have *undefined behavior*.

---

Also, `a` ***is*** initialized. It's initialized by the previous assignment of the result of the `strtok` call. Not that it matters, since `a` is not used in the call to `GetClassName`. Its status as initialized or not is irrelevant to the `GetClassName` call.

Comment: In C++ terminology, no, _`a` is not initialised_, although it has indeed been _assigned to_ by the result of the `strtok` call. I believe in colloquial C terminology, first assignment counts as "initialisation".

Comment: @RajeshRaghunathan ***Undefined behavior***. That's all that needs to be said. Sometimes it seems to work, sometimes is produces [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).